# NTP port is blocked. How to sync time? - 18.04

Tags: time, date, ntp

My server provider blocked NTP port because they said there was an NTP attack. Now I cannot sync date and time in my ubuntu 18.04 server.

How can I sync time?

This is `ntpdate -q 0.pool.ntp.org` result:

```
server 195.50.171.101, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
server 176.235.41.255, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
server 86.108.190.23, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
server 178.79.155.116, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
14 Nov 04:51:06 ntpdate[4027]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

This is `timedatectl` result:

```
                      Local time: Sat 2020-11-14 05:22:44 EST
                  Universal time: Sat 2020-11-14 10:22:44 UTC
                        RTC time: Sat 2020-11-14 09:55:35
                       Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -0500)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: @guiverc I dont know the exact release. I ınstalled it from web console and it says Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @guiverc I have edited title and question. But Do you have any answer to my question?

Comment: You provider may be blocking inbound connections, but outbound connections should be allowed (unless it is a very dumb ISP :)). Please, try the following command and paste the output in your original question: `ntpdate -q 0.pool.ntp.org` (You don't need to be `root` to run this command. But you may have to install it using `sudo apt install ntpdate`.)

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I have edited my question. Please take a look

Comment: Yes. It seems that there is no NTP connection. Can you also paste the output of `timedatectl` command?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I have added output

Comment: I suggest you contact your server provider (Can you share their name with us?). Time synchronization is a basic service that any serious server provider should provide. They may have an *internal NTP server* just for this purpose.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Their name is Keyubu. Local provider. I talked with them about this but they said they cannot enable it soon and I should manually set time

Comment: I think you live in Turkey and the service provider you are using is keyubu.com. I also live in Turkey, but I have never thought of using a VPS from a Turkish provider, because they are expensive, unreliable and due to **heavy Internet censorship** in Turkey, you cannot rely on a Turkish provider to do real business. For time synchronization you can do something *programmatically* by running a script periodically and obtaining the time from a **Web server**. However, this would not be a very reliable approach. Please search `linux time sync without ntp access` for some hints.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I'm using Hetzner for important data(such as database). But servers in turkey are microservices that doesnt contain anything important. So even i my server is blocked, I can create a new one in a minute. So. And its cheaper than german providers. Also I found and answer. Will share the answer here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [the `htpdate` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=htpdate). It has a service called `htpdate.service`.

After installing `htpdate` with the command `sudo apt install htpdate` you can monitor its status using the following command:

```
$ systemctl status htpdate.service
```

Please, note that this service will not be able to synchronize your clock very precisely, however an error of **about one second** will be acceptable in your case.

Comment: For other GNU/Linux OS without systemd (ex. Devuan) you can write a startup script as described in [Updating Time over HTTP](https://sabiancrash.blogspot.com/2013/04/updating-time-over-http-on-raspberry-pi.html) post